# need to create a matrix/pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a data frame as below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],
                    'Name2':['B','C','D','C','D','D','A','B'],'Marks2':[10,20,6,50, 88,23,140,9]})
df1
```

I need to create an output in the following format:
The index should only contain value A from Name1.

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1.query('Name1 == "A"').pivot('Name1', 'Name2', 'Marks2')
```

output:

```
Name2   B   C  D
Name1           
A      10  20  6
```

*NB. to remove the indexes names, add `.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)`.*